# Changing shapefile to fit inside feature of another

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip, geoprocessing, overlapping-features

I have shapefiles with maps of school districts by state. However, some of these districts go beyond the state's area, shown below. I want to preserve the districts, just remove all the bits going out into the lakes and such. How can I automatically adjust the boundries of the districts that extend beyond the state's land mass so that they don't any longer?

Ideally, using QGIS, but any solution is welcome. In other words, I'm just looking to cut off features in the school district shapefiles based on the Michigan feature in the U.S. map shapefile.

[image: Michigan school districts]
*Michigan school districts*

[image: Michigan school districts and state outline]
*Michigan school districts and state outline*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Joseph has mentioned in comments, the best way is to use a ["Clip tool"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#clip).

Besides, you can use ["Intersection"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#intersection).

Both can be found in

> Vector > Geoprocessing Tools

---

**References:**

- [GrindGIS | Basic Editing Geoprocessing Tools in QGIS](https://grindgis.com/software/qgis/basic-editing-tools-in-qgis)
- [QGIS Tutorials | Geoprocessing](https://nates-intro-to-qgis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/geoprocessing.html)

Comment: With a little bit of messing around with the settings, it worked like a charm! I don't see how the Clip tool could keep the features, but intersect did.